# What is the cubic feet of my washing machine?

Tags: washer

I will be purchasing a new washer in the near future and want to know the cubic feet of the one I will be replacing.  I have an old Whirlpool stock no. LXR7144E, model no. LXR7144EQ0, serial no. CF1603879.  I have tried looking it up online and I can find parts, manuals, etc. for it but nothing list the cubic feet.  Thanks for the help!

Jennifer

Comment: Listed Volume Capacity: 3.2 cu/ ft

Answer (score 1):

Stick a measuring device inside.  Measure the depth and diameter.  Convert those to feet.  volume = height times (diameter / 2) ^ 2 * pi.

For example, my washer is 12 inches deep (a front loader) and 22 inches in diameter.  1 foot times (22/12 / 2)^2 * pi = 2.6 cubic feet.

To clarify:

12 inches = 1.0 feet

22 inches = 22/12 feet = 1.8333 feet

convert 1.83333 feet from diameter to radius by dividing by 2 = 0.916666 feet

1.0 x (0.91666) ^ 2  x π =

0.84027777  x  π =

0.84027777  x 3.141592 =

2.63980994